# Appcelerator::Titanium::Real device:: Imageview is not showing the updated image from remote url

Tags: appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

In Real devices, Imageview is not showing the updated image from remote url. I have tried in simulator and emulator where there are no issues.

Could you please share your comments?

Thank you,
Jai.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a unique parameter to url to make sure it is not cached.

example

```
imageView.image: "http://www.google.com/profile/image0001.png" + "?t=" + new Date();
```

Where "http://www.google.com/profile/image0001.png" is your actual url.